# How to make this script move x and y axis at same time logitech ghub lua script

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

Hey I need some help getting this code to move on the x and the y axis. Right now, the code is only moving the mouse on the x axis but I believe it should be moving on the x and y axis. I don't know what I did wrong with the code, could someone help me. At first, all it did was move the x axis, but I believed all I had to do to get the y axis moving too was to add the same code for the x axis but change x to y to tell the script to move the y axis too but it didn't work.

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
function SmoothMouseMovement(x_speed, y_speed, duration)
    local last_x, last_y = 0, 0
    local tm_start = GetRunningTime()
    repeat
        Sleep(5)
        if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        local tm = math.min(GetRunningTime() - tm_start, duration)
        local x = math.floor(x_speed * tm)
        local y = math.floor(y_speed * tm)
        if x ~= last_x or y ~= last_y then
            MoveMouseRelative(x - last_x, y - last_y)
            last_x = x
            last_y = y
        end
    until tm >= duration
end
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    --OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")
    if IsKeyLockOn("capslock") and IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
        repeat
            local x_speed = 2  -- pixels per millisecond (amount of pixels mouse will move per ms)
            local duration = 30 -- milliseconds (amount of time mouse will move in one direction for)
            SmoothMouseMovement(x_speed, 0, duration)
            local y_speed = 1  -- pixels per millisecond (amount of pixels mouse will move per ms)
            local duration = 40 -- milliseconds (amount of time mouse will move in one direction for)
            SmoothMouseMovement(y_speed, 0, duration)
            local x_speed = -1  -- pixels per millisecond
            local duration = 30  -- milliseconds
            SmoothMouseMovement(x_speed, 0, duration)
            local y_speed = -2  -- pixels per millisecond (amount of pixels mouse will move per ms)
            local duration = 40 -- milliseconds (amount of time mouse will move in one direction for)
            SmoothMouseMovement(y_speed, 0, duration)
            MoveMouseRelative(0,0)
            PressAndReleaseMouseButton(2)
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end
end
```

Ok Edit#1 Here is the new code @Piglet. The reason I try to put it in the loop is because when I take MoveMouseRelative outside of the loop, it doesn't work at all, the mouse just doesn't move down.

```
if IsKeyLockOn("capslock") and IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
        repeat
            for i = 1, 1 do
                local x_speed = -4  -- pixels per millisecond (amount of pixels mouse will move per ms)
                local y_speed = 1  -- pixels per millisecond (amount of pixels mouse will move per ms)
                local duration = 10 -- milliseconds (amount of time mouse will move in one direction for)
                SmoothMouseMovement(x_speed, y_speed, duration)
            end
            for i = 1, 1 do
                local x_speed = 4  -- pixels per millisecond (amount of pixels mouse will move per ms)
                local y_speed = 1  -- pixels per millisecond (amount of pixels mouse will move per ms)
                local duration = 10 -- milliseconds (amount of time mouse will move in one direction for)
                SmoothMouseMovement(x_speed, y_speed, duration)
            end
            for i = 1, 1 do
                local x_speed = 4  -- pixels per millisecond (amount of pixels mouse will move per ms)
                local y_speed = -1  -- pixels per millisecond (amount of pixels mouse will move per ms)
                local duration = 10 -- milliseconds (amount of time mouse will move in one direction for)
                SmoothMouseMovement(x_speed, y_speed, duration)
            end
            for i = 1, 1 do
                local x_speed = -4  -- pixels per millisecond (amount of pixels mouse will move per ms)
                local y_speed = -1  -- pixels per millisecond (amount of pixels mouse will move per ms)
                local duration = 10 -- milliseconds (amount of time mouse will move in one direction for)
                SmoothMouseMovement(x_speed, y_speed, duration)
            end
            PressAndReleaseMouseButton(2)
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        MoveMouseRelative(0,20)
    end
end
```

Comment: please read through your code befor asking questions like this. your mistake is very obvious, given that you also have the implementation of `SmoothMouseMovement`. The first thing you do, if a function does not do what you expect is that you check if you call it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `SmoothMouseMovement(y_speed, 0, duration)` with `SmoothMouseMovement(0, y_speed, duration)`

If you want x and y to move at the same time use `SmoothMouseMovement(x_speed, y_speed, duration)` instead of `SmoothMouseMovement(x_speed, 0, duration)` and `SmoothMouseMovement(0, y_speed, duration)`

Comment: Hey thank you so much, you are right it was a easy mistake I should have picked up on. It works thanks to that correction thank you

Comment: hey if you could help me a little bit more i am not understanding one more thing. I am trying to add an additional movement that will move the mouse down for 1 second every time i press MB1 but it doesnt seem to work. I added this line of code right outside the repeat until loop as i dont want it to be repeated. 

```for i = 1, 10 do
            MoveMouseRelative(0,2)
        end```

But this does not work it doesnt move the mouse down at all

Comment: post a new question with more code.  why do you use a loop here? just move 20 pixels.

Comment: Hey i edited the question with additional code. When I take it out of the repeat until loop, it doesn't work. The mouse doesn't move down at all.

Comment: Also i want the mouse to move down for a specific amount of time, so I assumed the way to do that was to put the MoveMouseRelative in a loop and make the loop repeat itself for x amount of times but its not working as intended

Comment: I forgot to mention @Piglet